# nginx proxy_pass missing path

Tags: nginx, jenkins, proxypass

So I am running some `nginx` and `jenkins` in docker containers (same machine).

I have setup a proxy_pass in nginx as follows

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /jenkins/ {
        proxy_pass         http://infrastructure_jenkins_1:8080/;
    }
}
```

The redirect goes to `http://54.194.42.13/static/b703e301/css/layout-common.css` which results in a `404`.

How do i configure the proxy to include `/jenkins` in the path i.e. `http://54.194.42.13/jenkins/static/b703e301/css/layout-common.css` ?

Comment: 54.194.42.13 is the jenkins container? have you seen https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy ? maybe jenkins needs `--prefix=/jenkins`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing `/` from the `proxy_pass` statement. The trailing `/` is instructing `nginx` to substitute the value of the `location` statement (`/jenkins/`) with `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

For example, to reverse proxy without altering the original URI use:

```
location /jenkins/ {
    proxy_pass  http://infrastructure_jenkins_1:8080;
}
```